# How to paint on top of QListWidget in eventfilter in PyQt4/PySide?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qpainter, qlistwidget

I tried this on QLable and it works, I do not want to subclass the widget, because they are defined in .ui files, and I just need to do simple modification so I want to avoid delegate. If I put my code in paintEvent it works, but why I can not put it in eventfilter?

It seems it painted the square but it's below the listWidgetItem area.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class xxxx(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(xxxx, self).__init__(parent)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    # def paintEvent(self, event):
    #     p = QPainter()
    #     p.begin(self.viewport())
    #     p.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
    #     p.fillRect(QRect(0, 1, 20, 20), Qt.red)
    #     p.end()

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Paint:
            p = QPainter()
            # p.begin(self.viewport())
            p.begin(widget)
            p.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
            p.fillRect(QRect(0, 1, 20, 20), Qt.red)
            p.end()
            return True
        return QListWidget.eventFilter(self, widget, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = xxxx()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the event-filter on the viewport:

```
class xxxx(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(xxxx, self).__init__(parent)
        self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Paint and widget is self.viewport():
            p = QPainter()
            p.begin(widget)
            p.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
            p.fillRect(QRect(0, 1, 20, 20), Qt.red)
            p.end()
            return True
        return super(xxxx, self).eventFilter(widget, event)
```

Comment: why `return super....` instead of simply `false` ? wont false propagate too upwards

Comment: @qrtLs Because you must honour the return value of the base-class implementation - which could be `True` or `False`. (There will be dozens of different event types passing through this filter, not just paint events).

Comment: indeed honor, but true/false is ok, but why `return super(xxxx, self).eventFilter(widget, event)` (== should be not honored == false, right?)

Comment: @qrtLs Strictly speaking, the OPs event-filter isn't correct, because it doesn't check which object the event relates to. That isn't really relevant to their question, but I've now amended my answer to fix it. The base-class implementation must always be called so that all events, *for all objects*, are handled correctly. The OPs example doesn't actually install event-filters on any other objects, but the principle still holds, because one of the base-classes may have done so.

Comment: so return False is oke and implies the event is eaten and i am sure no other user-installed eventfilter is registered which might handle it too. otherwise i need super... etc.

Comment: @qrtLs No: returning `False` means the event was **not** handled. I would say always calling the base-class event-filter is generally more robust, because it doesn't need to know about any other implementation details (which could change in the future).